# POST request successful, but data get saved in the wrong way

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to send a POST request to an endpoint, I get a 200 response but the data I'm sending get saved wrongly in the DB;

I'd like to know if the fault lies in my post request or in the backend code that handles the request.

To be more specific: I'm sending a POST request to a Laravel + MariaDB backend. I didn't write the backend code, and all the "specifics" I got are:

> The post request has 3 fields:
>
> - user_id: the patient's id
> - password: the patients' password (same for all patients)
> - payload: a json payload structured this way:
>
>   - 'epoch_start' => 'required|numeric',
>   - 'epoch_end' => 'required|numeric|gte:epoch_start',
>   - 'size' => 'required|numeric|gt:0',
>   - 'temperature' => 'required|array|min:size',
>   - 'pressure' => 'required|array|min:size',
>   - 'movement' => 'required|array|min:size',

Here is the Controller that handles the request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Response;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Sensor;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class SensorController extends Controller
{
    public function storeData(Request $request) {
        if ($request->has(['user_id', 'password', 'payload'])) {
            $password = $request->get('password');
            $user_id = $request->get('user_id');

            $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->firstOrFail();
            if($user->role != "patient") return new Response('Forbidden', 403);
            if($password != "HIDDENPASS") return new Response('Forbidden', 403);


            $payload = $request->get('payload');
            $data = json_decode($payload, true);

            $rules = [
                'epoch_start' => 'required|numeric',
                'epoch_end' => 'required|numeric|gte:epoch_start',
                'size' => 'required|numeric|gt:0',
                'temperature' => 'required|array|min:size',
                'pressure' => 'required|array|min:size',
                'movement' => 'required|array|min:size',
                'temperature.*' => 'numeric',
                'pressure.*' => 'numeric',
                'movement.*' => 'numeric',
            ];

            $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

            if ($validator->passes()) {
                $s = new Sensor;
                $s->user_id = $user->id;
                $s->epoch_start = Carbon::parse($data["epoch_start"]);
                $s->epoch_end = Carbon::parse($data["epoch_end"]);
                $s->size = $data["size"];
                $s->temperature = json_encode($data["temperature"]);
                $s->pressure = json_encode($data["pressure"]);
                $s->movement = json_encode($data["movement"]);
                $s->save();
                response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
            } else {
                dd($validator->errors());
            }

        } else {
            return new Response('Forbidden', 403);
        }  
    }
}
```

If I try [this Post request using Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WHzs.png) (I tried using curl and python's request module, too) I get a 200 response, and the data get saved to the DB [in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4PP3.png).

The problem lies with the fields "temperature", "pressure" and "movement", to be more specific with the double quotes surrounding the array: the computations involving this data made by the web app are all wrong but, if I manually remove the double quotes (from PhpMyAdmin) the computations are right.

For the sake of completeness [here is the table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9FtW.png).

Is there a way to avoid the double quotes surrounding those fields?

Is my POST request at fault here, or is it a back-end-related thing?

I'm not familiar with PHP, but if I am not mistaken the handling of those data should be managed by these lines:

```
$s->temperature = json_encode($data["temperature"]);
$s->pressure = json_encode($data["pressure"]);
$s->movement = json_encode($data["movement"]);
```

and the json_encode returns a string, so I'm beginning to think that the backend code is at fault here, but I'd like a second opinion.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Ok, thanks to @samuel-olufemi answer and @sumit comment I can conclude that the json_encode coupled with the longtext datatype used by MariaDB is the main problem.
So I tried to store the array values without encoding them, changing those 3 lines to:

```
$s->temperature = $data["temperature"];
$s->pressure = $data["pressure"];
$s->movement = $data["movement"];
```

and the data are stored without double quotes, as per my desire. Thanks all for your help and your time.

Comment: Try dumping `json_encode($data["temperature"])`, what is the output?

Comment: @summit I added a  `dd(json_encode($data["temperature"]));`  to the controller code, and this is the output:
`<pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1140620826 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="7 characters">[1,1,0]</span>"
</pre>`
so, a 7 characters string

Comment: Well it looks like the quotes are part of the output from json_encode, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Implementation is right. The problem is due to the way Maria DB longtext data type  manages JSON data.

you can check out this answer

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192754/json-functions-double-quotes-added-when-going-through-a-variable